# Decrementing Cx and Dx seem to do nothing in Assembly Graphic Mode

Tags: assembly, x86-16, fasm

I am trying to build a snake like game but for some reason I can't decrement cx and dx and show the pixels, incrementing works just fine.
Take a look

[image]

Read Key function:

```
readkey:
 mov ah, 07h
 int 21h
 mov [key], al

 cmp byte[key], ESC
 je endProgram

 cmp byte[key], 'a'
 je key_a

 cmp byte[key], 'd'
 je key_d

 cmp byte[key], 'w'
 je key_w

 cmp byte[key], 's'
 je key_s
 jne readkey
```

Key Functionality:

```
key_a:
 dec cx
 call pixel

key_d:
 inc cx
 call pixel

key_w:
 dec dx
 call pixel


key_s:
 inc dx
 call pixel
```

Pixel Function

```
pixel:
 mov ah, 0ch
 mov al, 5
 mov bh, 0
 int 10h
ret
```

For some reason I can't move the pixel when I decrement dx or cx.

Everything needs to be FASM compatible.

Comment: You currently have fall-through from each previous case to the next, because you've got nothing after each `call` that jumps to a different location.

Comment: I've figure it out now, thank you! I needed to add a jmp readkey to every statement

Comment: Or more simply, `jmp pixel` and then have the `pixel:` block end with `jmp readkey`.  i.e. make `pixel` just a simple block inside your function so you can thread jumps through it instead of call/ret and having to jmp somewhere else.